# Java Webstart Jar Signing: Can it be signed partially?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have had a brief search in StackOverflow, it seems that for a webstart application, if some of the JARs are signed and other are unsigned, it will end up treated as unsigned if unsigned code are accessed in call stack.

However, what if I only put resources (e.g. config files) in an unsigned JAR? (In fact I have some environment-dependent configs that I want to centralize in a separate JAR).  If all other JARs containing "code" are signed, will it runs fine as signed application?

Comment: This is "Mixed code"-hell.  Can't you sign the config jar too?

Comment: I may.  In fact I am just trying to see if there is easier way for the deploying team to create the "config jar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsigned Jars can be put in a sand-boxed extension and used by an app. that requests `j2ee-application-client-permissions` or `all-permissions`.

To avoid the mixed code warning that this produces, see [Deploying Signed Applications and Applets Securely Without a Mixed Code Warning](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest).

Comment: Although finally I haven't take this approach, this is a working solution.  However, one should pay attention that using such approach seems cause a confirmation box everytime the app startup, confirming for webstart of mixing signed and unsigned jars.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind in such a scenario: you can NOT have Java classes from signed and unsigned (or signed using different certificates) JARs in the same package - it will cause a SecurityException during class loading.